# Load multiple text files from different folders into one file and account for special characters

Tags: python, file, replace

I am trying to read multiple text files located in different folders into one file and adjust for weird format issues, especially special characters while reading.

Here is what my input files looks like:

```
cat date        col1               col2              col3
x   3/1/2010    " 823,312,356   "" 145,019,711 "" "" 666,666 "" "       
x   3/8/2010    " 3,423,115,838  "" 111,422,457 "" "" 311,512 "" "      
x   3/15/2010   " 4,117,664,854  ""115,115,141 "" "" 213,550 """        
x   3/22/2010    527,337,127    " "" 153,423,891 "" "" 216,365 "" " 
x   3/29/2010   "459,227,151"   " "" 57,213,333 ""    454,718   
x   4/6/2010    "367,221,146"   " "" 72,458,231 """ "264,130"
x   4/13/2010        -                 -              $0
```

I have a lot of weird formatting issues I need to account for.

I was trying this:

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob(data_path + "*.txt")

with open(data_path +"final.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            infile = re.sub(r"[-()\"#@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", infile)
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

But I get an error message, saying:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Has someone faced the same problem?

Comment: Why do you use 'b' when opening the files? Have you tried omitting it?

Comment: The 'b' stands for binary mode. You are right, I don´t necessarily need it. But omitting it does not solve the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> with open(f, "rb") as infile:
>     infile = re.sub(r"[-()\"#@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", infile)
>     outfile.write(infile.read())
> ```

First, using `'b'` when opening a file treats the file contents as a `bytes` object, not a string (type `str`). This does not work with the regular expression pattern that is given as a string. So you should just omit the `'b'`. Since the remaining `'r'` is the default mode for opening a file, you can just omit the second argument for `open()` entirely.

Next, you are confusing a *file object* with the file *contents*, and the order of operations is wrong.

`infile.read()` reads the contents of the file and returns them as a string (when omitting the `'b'`). This string can be passed to `re.sub`.

So the correct order would be:

```
with open(f) as infile:
    text = infile.read()
    replaced_text = re.sub(r"[-()\"#@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", text)
    outfile.write(replaced_text)
```